# cannot identify image file when using Image Open

Tags: python, pandas

Currently i am trying to crop all my dataset image
i have the data xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax in the csv and the image name
but i am facing this trouble when i try to crop the image

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg'
```

Here's my **code**

```
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd


for index, row in data.iterrows():
  input_name  = os.path.join("imagesXRP", row["filename"])
  xmin  = row["xmin"]
  ymin = row['ymin']
  xmax  = row["xmax"]
  ymax = row['ymax']
  im = Image.open(input_name)
  im1 = im.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  im1.show()
```

Any answer would be helpfull

Thank you so much

Update i use `hexdump -C imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg | head -10` just like what Mr. Robert said on the comment and it show this

```
00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01  |......JFIF......|
00000010  00 01 00 00 ff fe 00 11  4c 61 76 63 35 38 2e 31  |........Lavc58.1|
00000020  33 34 2e 31 30 30 00 ff  db 00 43 00 08 32 32 3b  |34.100....C..22;|
00000030  32 3b 44 44 44 44 44 44  51 4b 51 54 54 54 51 51  |2;DDDDDDQKQTTTQQ|
00000040  51 51 54 54 54 5a 5a 5a  6a 6a 6a 5a 5a 5a 54 54  |QQTTTZZZjjjZZZTT|
00000050  5a 5a 64 64 6a 6a 73 76  73 6d 6d 6a 6d 76 76 7d  |ZZddjjsvsmmjmvv}|
00000060  7d 7d 96 96 8f 8f af af  b5 d7 d7 ff ff c4 00 86  |}}..............|
00000070  00 00 02 03 01 01 01 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 01 03 04 02 05 06  07 08 01 01 01 01 01 01  |................|
00000090  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04  |................|
```

Comment: Have you looked at this file to see what it contains?  The error seems pretty clear.

Comment: its just normal jpg/image file from what i see...

Comment: Can you do `hexdump -C imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg | head -10` and show it to us?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Mr.Roberts, i have edited the question after using your code and the output are like that

Comment: Hmm, that looks like a bog-standard JPEG 1.2 file, created by ffmpeg.  Is it just this one file that gives you trouble, or is it all of them?  Perhaps the end of the file was damaged.

Comment: i try with other photos but it doesnt give any output but no error, like the im1.show doesnt show anything, but when i use the Data16_173_55.jpg it show the error